# Immersions: What is it, what does it, who names it

Tags: analysis, matrix-rank, jacobian

In the lecture notes I'm reading, an *immersion* is defined as a $C^{\infty}$  map $f:U\rightarrow V$ between open subsets $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ resp. $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, with $m\leq n$, such that for all $x\in U$ the rank of $Df(x)$ be maximal, i.e., be equal to $m$.

My question is: 1)  Does this mean that the $Df(x)$ is constant as long as $x$ varies of a connected component of $U$? If yes, how can I prove this?

2) Is this definition standard? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)) only states this definition for manifolds and that is too advanced for me, so that I'd be able to see if that definition matches this one.

Comment: Just a technical note, if $m \leq n$ then $min\{m,n \} = m$ so that last bit is a little redundant

Comment: @OsamaGhani right; thx, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. An example would be the map $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},~~x\mapsto (x,x^2)$. It maps the real line onto the standard parabola. This is an immersion, because $Df(x) = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2x\end{pmatrix}$ and this matrix of size $2\times1$ has rank $1$, which is maximal. But you can also see that $Df(x)$ is nowhere constant (and $U=\mathbb{R}$ has just one component).

2) This is a standard definition, a special case of the definition on wikipedia. Quote:

> Equivalently, $f$ is an immersion if its derivative has constant rank equal to the dimension of $M$:
>   $\text{rank}\, D_p f = \text{dim}\, M$

You don't know what a manifold is, but in your case, $D_p f$ is nothing else then $Df(p)$ and the manifold is the open set $U$, which has dimension $m$. Note that you wrote $m\leq n$, so $\min(m,n)=m$

Comment: +1. nice answer; I actually made a slight error in my question - instead of changing my all the relevant parts, I made a new one question, which can be viewed as a generalization of this one, in case you're interested https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862488/regular-maps-what-is-it-what-does-it-who-names-it