# Regular maps: What is it, what does it, who names it

Tags: analysis, matrix-rank, jacobian

Consider the following definition of *regular* map: a $C^{\infty}$  map $f:U\rightarrow V$ between open subsets $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ resp. $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, such that for all $x\in U$ the rank of $Df(x)$ be maximal, i.e., be equal to $\min\{m,n\}$.

My questions are: 1)  Does this mean that the **rank of $Df(x)$** is constant as long as $x$ varies of a connected component of $U$? If yes, how can I prove this?

2) I could not find this definition on wikipedia. Can it perhaps be found under a different name?

Comment: Since the rank is maximal and $m, n$ are fixed, then yes the rank is constant, not only on each connected component, but overall. You can note that if the rank is maximal at one point, then it’s maximal in a neighbourhood around that point. It’s true that this implies that the rank on each _connected_ component is constant, but moreso they’re all maximal so they’re all the same rank. Such maps would be called submersions or immersions, and you can find definitions of these on Wikipedia.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Ah, thanks! Just a small question: If I only assume the rank is maximal in a single point, not on all of the domain, then it's also maximal in a neighborhood around that point; this is clear. But what argument do I then need to use to obtain that it's maximal on the whole connected component containing that point?

Comment: @temo I think this is not true. Look at $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$. So we have $m=1, n=2$. We obtain $Df(t) = \begin{pmatrix}2t\\3t^2\end{pmatrix}$, which has $\text{rank}=1$ iff $t\neq0$. So it's maximal outside $0$, but not in the whole connected component. Note that still every point with maximal rank has a neighborhood with maximal rank.

Comment: @temo You can use a connectedness argument. Let $S = \{ p \in U | p$ has an neighbourhood about it where $Df$ has maximal rank $\}$, then show that $S$ is both open and closed, and hence represents a connected component

Comment: @osama Ghani, that's the way one would prove this. But in this case it's not possible, since S is not closed. See my comment for a counterexample.

Comment: Ah you’re absolutely correct. I forgot that rank is semi-continuous so you can’t necessarily show that the complement of S is open.